# VPN sin conexión a Internet

Tags: macos, centos, vpn, centos7

He instalado una OpenVPN en CentOS, hasta aquí todo normal.

Creo el archivo de configuración clien, para tunnelblick mac con extensión .ovpn. La conexión aparentemente se realiza sin ningún inconveniente. Pero cuando trato de conectar a cualquier web, no tengo conexión a Internet en mi MacBook.

Curiosamente sólo puedo conectar con servicios que estén alojados en mi servidor CentOS. Como GitLab, NextCloud, Apache etc...

No sé a qué puede deberse esto, estoy bastante perdido :(.

En mi servidor CentOS están presentes las siguientes interfaces de red.

```
1: lo: <LOOPBACK,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 65536 qdisc noqueue state UNKNOWN qlen 1
    link/loopback 00:00:00:00:00:00 brd 00:00:00:00:00:00
    inet 127.0.0.1/8 scope host lo
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet6 ::1/128 scope host 
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
2: eth0: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc pfifo_fast state UP qlen 1000
    link/ether 00:22:4d:86:87:8e brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    inet x.xxx.xxx.xxx/24 brd x.xxx.xxx.xxx scope global eth0
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet6 2001:41d0:8:d8c3::1/128 scope global 
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet6 fe80::222:4dff:fe86:878e/64 scope link 
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
3: tun0: <POINTOPOINT,MULTICAST,NOARP,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc pfifo_fast state UNKNOWN qlen 100
    link/none 
    inet 192.168.30.1 peer 192.168.30.2/32 scope global tun0
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet6 fe80::74a3:1924:5fee:55dc/64 scope link flags 800 
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
```

Tengo agregada las siguientes reglas en iptables.

```
iptable -t nat -A POSTROUTING -s 192.168.30.0/32 -o eth0 -j MASQUERADE

iptable -t nat -A POSTROUTING -s 192.168.30.0/32 -o tun0 -j MASQUERADE

 iptables -A INPUT -i eth0 -p udp --dport 1194 -j ACCEPT
 iptables -A INPUT -i tun0 -p udp --dport 1194 -j ACCEPT
```

clien.ovpn

```
client
dev tun
proto udp
remote x.x.x.x 1194
float
resolv-retry infinite
nobind
route x.x.x.x 255.255.255.0
dhcp-option DNS 8.8.8.8
cipher AES-256-CBC
remote-cert-tls server
#----- Sección de firma y certificados -----
ca   /Users/xxxx/xxx/ca.crt
cert /Users/xxxx/xxxx/cliente1.crt
key  /Users/xxx/xxx/cliente1.key
#-------------------------------------------
compress lzo
verb 3
```

server.conf

```
dev tun
proto udp
port 1194

#----- Sección de firma y certificados -----
ca keys/ca.crt
cert keys/server.crt
key keys/server.key
dh keys/dh2048.pem
#-------------------------------------------

server 192.168.30.0 255.255.255.0

push "redirect-gateway def1 bypass-dhcp"
push "dhcp-option DNS 8.8.8.8"
push "dhcp-option DNS 8.8.4.4"
ifconfig-pool-persist ipp.txt
compress lzo
keepalive 15 130
persist-key
persist-tun
cipher AES-256-CBC
log-append /var/log/openvpn.log
verb 3
```

Answer (score 0):

Creo que el problema está en "redirect-gateway" en la configuración del servidor.
Esa orden, le dice al cliente que use el servidor de VPN como gateway.
Para ese problema, tienes 2 posibles soluciones:
1) Lo quitas y comienzas a navegar con tu conexión y solo usas los servicios del servidor.
2) Activas el fordward de paquetes en el servidor y haces las reglas de iptables para poder usar tu servidor como gateway.

Comment: Ya tenía habilitado IP forwarding, el problema estaba en un error en la regla iptables.